# More than one nomenclature/acronyms list in the document

Tags: equations, acronyms, nomenclature

I would like to have more than one nomenclature/acronyms in my document:

1. Below every equation
2. At the beginning of the document a complete nomenclature of all symbols used.

Do you know whether it is possible to do this using `nomencl` or `acronym` package ?

Or in other words, how to make `\nomenclature` visible below an equation?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I've found the solution to my problem :)

Thanks to [@karlkoeller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153439/43565) and [@Phssthpok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741556/2669472) you can see code below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
e = m * c^2
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{e}{energy}
\mathgloss{m}{mass}
\mathgloss{c}{speed of light}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```