# Alignment in \gls using package glossaries in LaTeX?

Tags: glossaries

I'm struggling with `glossaries` package for a while...

I would like to change the standard alignment in the **link text** of `\gls`.
I've used example code from [equation variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4741556/2669472):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}
    \gls{#1} = #2
}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
e = m * c^2
\end{equation}
in which\\
\mathgloss{e}{energy}\\
\mathgloss{m}{mass}\\
\mathgloss{c}{speed of light}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

..and got the results:

[image: example]

I would like to change the alignment of the all descriptions to be more like in a table.
I tried putting the code in the regular table but it didn't work.

I also tried the code below, but the question is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

 \makeglossary

  \newglossaryentry{aaaaaa}{name=aaaaaa,description={speed of light},symbol={km/s}}
  \newglossaryentry{b}{name=b,description={mass},symbol={kg}}

  \renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\small{#1}}
  \renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \glsgenentryfmt
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\space -\space \glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}{,\space \glsentrysymbol{\glslabel}}%}

 \begin{document}
 \gls{aaaaaa} \\
 \gls{b}

 \printglossaries
 \end{document}
```

Do you have any suggestions how to do this ?
Or maybe there is a different/better approach to have equation variables description below the equation and at the same time in the glossary ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a `description` environment used in this way (requires `enumitem`):

```
\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
e = m * c^2
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{e}{energy}
\mathgloss{m}{mass}
\mathgloss{c}{speed of light}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to adjust the spacing between items, you can work on the `description`'s parameters `topsep` and `partopsep`. For example, with the configuration `partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt`, you have the spacing like in normal paragraphs

```
\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}
```

[image]

In my opinion, anyway, it looks better with only `topsep=0pt`

```
\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em,topsep=0pt]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice @karlkoeller :) Do you know how to change line spacing only in the equation description ?

Comment: @Michal Of course, see the edited question. Remember that you can accept the answer, if it solves your problem, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: @Michal You're welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: Using this code I wasn't able to use as a name `e_{2}` or `$e_{2}$` nor `\ensuremath{e_{2}` Do you have any suggestions how to fix this ?

Comment: @Michal `$e_{2}$` works fine for me. Try deleting the `.gls` file before recompiling.

Comment: Yep, you were right ! Thank you again @karlkoeller :)