# Add symbol field to \newglossaryentry in \newcommand

Tags: glossaries

This is a continuation of my question [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153434/43565).

For a given code I would like to add symbol. For example:

`\mathgloss{m}{mass}{kg}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[2]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
e = m * c^2
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{e}{energy}
\mathgloss{m}{mass}
\mathgloss{c}{speed of light}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I tried writing ("a blind shot"):

```
\newcommand{\mathgloss}[3]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2},symbol={#3}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2 #3%
    \end{description}%
}
```

...but I missed the target.

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working as you wish? If I substitute your code and add an additional argument to each occurrence of \mathgloss in your MWE, it compiles and prints the symbol just as you've asked. If the issue is that the symbol is not displayed in your *glossary*, make sure you are using a style which supports printing symbols as not all do.

Comment: With my code I got an error `File ended while scanning use of \mathgloss \input{chapters/}`

Comment: I've found the bugs. Firstly I had to delete *.gls file (as @karlkoeller advised me). Secondly I missed one bracket :/ Anyway thank you for your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to choose a glossary style that prints the `symbol` field. You can find them on the Table 15.1 of the `glossaries` documentation.

[image]

If you choose, for example, the `index` style, you have then to print the glossary with

```
\printglossary[style=index]
```

MWE (I also changed a little the definition of `\mathgloss`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mathgloss}[3]{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#1},description={#2},symbol={#3}}%
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3em]%
      \item[\gls{#1}]#2 (\textbf{#3})%
    \end{description}%
}

\begin{document}

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
e = m * c^2
\end{equation}
in which
\mathgloss{e}{energy}{J}
\mathgloss{m}{mass}{Kg}
\mathgloss{c}{speed of light}{m/s}

\printglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

Output (document):

[image]

Output (glossary):

[image]